# Where can I decide the number of posts to display on the blog index page?

Tags: themes, frontpage

My blog posts index page (http://katievb.com/blog/) is showing only 1 blog post at a time; I want it to show more.

I am currently using [X Theme](http://theme.co/x/) as my WordPress theme, but a similar problem happens even if I try using Twenty Fifteen or Twenty Twelve or other standard themes. (The blog index page still just shows 1 blog post.)

I would think it would show 6 per page like this demo: http://theme.co/x/demo/integrity/1/blog/.

I found this [similar (very old) question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53180/blog-page-showing-only-first-post) but it did not help me.

It seems like there is a `posts_per_page` variable that must be set as `1` right now, and I'd like it to be `6`.

But I'm surprised the default would be `1` and that it persists across all themes.  Where can I change it, or how can I change my child theme of X?

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question, but did you ever go into Customize and change Front Page to "Display a Static Page?" That is the only way I can think that would make it persist across themes (unless you have some sort of plugin interference).

Comment: Thanks. Your comment inspired me to go back and look at all the settings again, and I discovered the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I went to `Settings > Reading` (at `/wp-admin/options-reading.php`).

I already had these settings:

- Front page displays:

  - **A static page**

    - Front page: **Home**
    - Posts page: **Blog**
- Blog pages show at most  **1** posts

That last line I had never noticed before (even when looking for it right here in this admin panel)!

Rookie mistake.

I was able to change it to 6.